# Side by side DIVs with progress meter

Tags: html, css

I've been reading numerous articles on side-by-side divs.  There's something subtly wrong with what I'm doing that's preventing it from working.  Ideally, I want to have my 3 divs appear on one line, each occupying a fixed amount of space. Something like this [15%][60%][25%]

The middle [60%] div is a progress meter bar.  I do this by having a div within a div and then using angular ng-style set the expression for the percentage width of my meter.

The progress meter part is working, but I cannot seem to put it all together on one line.

[image]

```
    <div ng-repeat="rec in records">
      <div>
         Items
      </div>
      <div ng-style="$scope.outerObj">
         <div ng-style="rec.innerObj"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {{rec.complete}} of {{rec.number}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

The $scope.outerObj is just the following expression:

```
$scope.outerObj = {
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'border-style': 'solid',
    'width': '220px'
};
```

NOTE - you may ask (like I did), "why can't I just make that outerObj a class and reference it from the outer div like this: `<div class="outerObj">`?  If I do, then the outer div border disappears and you don't get the sense of a progress meter.  I could only get it to work by making it also an ng-style.

The rec.innerObj looks like this:

```
rec.innerObj = {
                'width': (rec.complete ? (rec.complete / rec.number)*100 : 0) + '%',
                'background-color': 'blue',
                'height': '10px'
            };
```

So with all this, I have never been able to get the full combination of what I want:

Item [progress meter] X of Y

I've changed the display from 'inline-block' to just 'inline' and that puts things all on one line, but then my progress meter is all screwed up.

So many tries with different combinations and I've never got it to work, thus turning to the experts here.

Comment: Have you tried putting `inline-block` on *all* 3 inner divs? That ought to work.

Comment: same result (no difference)

Comment: ok...correcting myself.  that DID work!  thanks @mpen.  The reason it looked liked it didn't is that it appears the size of the outer container was forcing it to wrap.  I defined the width on the outer-most div to be 500px and then it went on 1 line.  Thank you!